# Show:$ \frac 12 n (n+1)=(n+1)(\frac 12 n+1)=\frac 12 (n+1)(n+2)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

Given:

$$ \sum_{k=1}^n k=1+2+3+\dots +n=\frac 12 n (n+1)$$

Show:

$$  1+2+3+\dots +n+(n+1)=(n+1)(\frac 12 n+1)=\frac 12 (n+1)(n+2)$$

The following is me wallowing in ignorance and failing to derive $\frac 12 (n+1)(n+2)$.

$ +(n+1)$ on both sides

$$ 1+2+3+\dots +n+(n+1)=\frac 12 n (n+1)+(n+1)$$

Gives

$$ 1+2+3+\dots +n+(n+1)=(\frac 12 n^2+ \frac 12n)+(n+1)$$
$$ 1+2+3+\dots +n+(n+1)=(\frac 12 n^2+ \frac 32 n+1)$$
$$ 2\cdot [1+2+3+\dots +n+(n+1)]=(n^2+ 3n+2)$$
$$ 2\cdot [1+2+3+\dots +n+(n+1)]=(n+ \frac 32)^2- \frac 14$$

Comment: $$\frac{n(n+1)}2+(n+1)=\frac{n+1}2(n+2)=\frac{(n+1)\{(n+1)+1\}}2$$ as required

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I don't comprehend the first = sign/jump.

Comment: I've taken out the factor $\frac{n+1}2$ from the two terms to be added

Comment: You are wrong when you try to expand.

Answer (score 2):

As  lab bhattacharjee  said in comments:

$$\frac{n(n+1)}{2}+(n+1)=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}+\frac{2(n+1)}{2}=\frac{(n+1)}{2}\cdot (n+2)=\frac 12 (n+1)(n+2)$$

$$ $$